# rails replace path in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, replace

I have a string that may have a path to a file. Example src="/folder/whatever". How do I replace that path with src="http://www.sitename.com/folder/whatever ?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing to me. Can you clarify and give examples perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

If your string contains `src="/..."`, possibly many times, do this:

```
string.gsub!(/\bsrc="(\/[^"]*)"/, 'src="http://www.sitename.com\1"')
```

If your string contains the URL only, do this:

```
src.replace('http://www.sitename.com' + src)
```

More information about `String#gsub` and `String#gsub!` here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000832

Comment: That would work if I just wanted to append the full url to the front of the string, but I need to find the src inside of a string and then change that src

Comment: Added another answer which finds all instances of src=

Answer (score 0):

[route helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html). use url instead of path.

Answer (score 0):

i like pts's solution, but i might remove the slash from the regex...so it would be:

```
string.gsub!(/\bsrc="([^"]*)"/, 'src="replacement_text\1"')
```

use the \1 to access the back reference